# Why isn't my function returning a value from the innermost then()/catch() promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The code below adds a document into the current user's friends collection and the target user's friends collection. This part is working fine, but I'm having an issue with returning a value to the client. I've ensured that the client code is working fine, but I don't quite yet understand Typescript well enough to know what I'm doing wrong here.

**What the code currently does:**
The code returns `69` and the current user's uid.

**What the code needs to do:**
The code needs to return the appropriate return values based on wherever it ends up. In the Firebase console, I see that the code executes all the way up to the line `console.log('_addFriend Finished adding friend.')`. The two lines after that assign return values `1` and `Friend request sent!`, but the client doesn't receive these values. Why isn't the code returning these?

```
exports.addFriend = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log('_addFriend: ');
  const uid1 = context?.auth?.uid as string //current user 
  const targetUser = data.targetUser 
  var username1: string = ''
  var returnVal: number = 69
  var returnMsg: string = uid1 
  
  if (uid1) {
    var uid2: string;
    const currentUsersFriendsColl = 'friends_' + uid1
    await TS_doesUserExist(targetUser)
    .then(result => {
      if (result[0] == 1) {
        console.log('_addFriend: targetUser ', targetUser, ' exists.')
        uid2 = result[1]
        const targetUsersFriendsColl = 'friends_' + uid2
        TS_getUserInfo('uid', uid1, 'username')
        .then(getUserInfo_result => {
          console.log('_addFriend getUserInfo_result is about to be evaluated')
          console.log('_addFriend getUserInfo_result[0]: ', getUserInfo_result[0])
          if (getUserInfo_result[0] == 1) {
            console.log('_addFriend getUserInfo_result[0]=1')
            username1 = getUserInfo_result[1]
            //Insert into current user's friends list
            const currentUserDoc = admin.firestore().collection(currentUsersFriendsColl).doc();
            currentUserDoc.set({
              createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              stat: 2, //pending
              friendUID: uid2,
              friendUsername: targetUser,
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('_addFriend: About to insert into target users friends collection')
              //Insert into target user's friends list
              const friendsDoc = admin.firestore().collection(targetUsersFriendsColl).doc();
              friendsDoc.set({
                createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                stat: 2, //pending
                friendUID: uid1,
                friendUsername: username1,
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log('_addFriend Finished adding friend.')
                returnVal = 1
                returnMsg = 'Friend request sent!'
                
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log('_addFriend error adding to target users friends collec: ', error)
                returnVal = 0
                returnMsg = 'Error all the way inside: ' + error 
                
              })    
                    
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('_addFriend error: ', error)
              returnVal = 0
              returnMsg = 'Error1: ' + error 
              
            })
            
          } else {
            console.log('_addFriend: In else, result was 0.')
            returnVal = 0
            returnMsg = 'Current user does not exist.'  
                     
          }
          
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('_TS_getUserInfo error: ', error)
          returnVal = 0
          returnMsg = 'Could not find current user info.'
           
        })
        
      } else {
        console.log('_TS_doesUserExist: targetUser ', targetUser, ' does not exist.')
        returnVal = result[0]
        returnMsg = result[2]
        
      }
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('_TS_doesUserExist error: ', error)
      returnVal = 0
      returnMsg = 'Error2: ' + error
      
    });
    
  }
  else {
    console.log('_addFriend error: User is not authorized');
    returnVal = 0
    returnMsg = 'User is not authorized.'
  }
  return {result: returnVal, message: returnMsg}  
});
```

Comment: You're mixing async/await with then/catch again.  That's never a good idea.

Comment: @DougStevenson which do you recommend between the two?

Answer (score 0):

A question I have in regards to what you are seeing on your end, does the console statement happen AFTER the client gets the 69 and other values?

I believe at the location where you are calling TS_getUserInfo inside the TS_doesUserExist `then` might be where your problem is. You'll need to `return` that promise chain if you want it to be awaited by the await for TS_doesUserExist.

Then just to explain what I believe I am seeing, if I am reading the nesting right, is that you are:

1. Calling await on TS_doesUserExist
2. The main block stops there. Waits for TS_doesUserExist to process
3. It then enters the then block and invokes your TS_getUserInfo function
4. After invoking the TS_getUserInfo function the original promise from  TS_doesUserExist resolves
5. Main block continues and sends the message to the client
6. Main block finishes allows event loop to loop back around to TS_getUserInfo
7. TS_getUserInfo resolves, enters then block prints your log and assigns values

So from that, returning TS_getUserInfo should allow it to be awaited your original await as it will then become part of the TS_doesUserExist promise chain and resolve your console and values prior to sending the message to the client.

Abbreviated code example of what I believe needs to happen:

```js
exports.addFriend = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { 
  const targetUser = data.targetUser; 
  var returnVal: number = 69;
  var returnMsg: string = uid1;
  
  if (uid1) {
    await TS_doesUserExist(targetUser)
      .then(result => {
        //...other code you want to process before calling TS_getUserInfo...

        // This is where I believe you need your return
        return TS_getUserInfo('uid', uid1, 'username')
          .then(() => {
            console.log('_addFriend Finished adding friend.')
            returnVal = 1
            returnMsg = 'Friend request sent!'
          });
    });
  }

  return {result: returnVal, message: returnMsg} 
});
```

Documentation from MDN on the promise.then function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

The chaining section there should give some more insight into that functionality as well.

Comment: Do I just need to add the keyword `return` alone or do I need to add `return {result: returnVal, message: returnMsg}`? I would assume the former since I'm only returning to the awaiting function, not to the client, right?

Comment: I'm brand new to TS btw, so sorry if that's a dumb question lol

Comment: I tossed an edit with a abbreviated code example based on this, but yes I believe you are correct that it would be that former where you are just returning to the awaiting function. Though I guess it wouldn't be just the return keyword alone, but you would be returning the promise that you want to ensure evaluates first before the original await completes. In this case the `TS_getUserInfo` function.